# Finding Area of region between cruves

Tags: calculus, area

I'm given $$y = \frac{4}{1+x^4}  $$ and $$y = 2x^2$$

I know I have to integrate, but I'm not really sure how to find the limits to integrate at.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: sketch the curves, figure out boundary values of the area in question, and integrate the difference of the two curves.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Figure out where the two functions are equal:

$$\frac{4}{1+x^4}=2x^2$$